# How to check if a list contains all the elements of another list INCLUDING duplicates

Tags: python

e.g.

```
t = ["A", "A", "A", "b", "b"]
s = ["A", "A", "b", "b"]
```

s does not contain every element in t. t contains every element in s.

I came up with this but wonder if there is a more efficient way

```
def check(l1, l2):
    for i in l2:
        if(l2.count(i) > l1.count(i)):
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: could be -> `all(elem in s for elem in t)`

Comment: You could use Counters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Repeated calls to `list.count` (for the same list) are very inefficient. You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and how it implements differences:

```
from collections import Counter

def contains(l1, l2):
    return not (Counter(l2) - Counter(l1))

>>> contains(["A", "A", "A", "b", "b"], ["A", "A", "b", "b"])
True
>>> contains(["a", "a", "b"], ["a", "b"])
True
>>> contains(["a", "b"], ["a", "a", "b"])
False
>>> contains(["a", "a", "b"], ["a", "b", "c"])
False
```

Comment: I think this doesn't give the expected result if l2 contains an element which is not in l1

Comment: @mcsoini It does. Just test it with different lists.

Comment: Those elements will retain a rest count in the counter difference (l2 - l1), and therefore render it truthy, and thereby its negation falsy. Which is the correct result.

Comment: My bad. Very elegant

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Counter-based approach:

```
from collections import Counter

counter_s = Counter(s)

all(counter_s.get(key_t, 0) >= count_t
    for key_t, count_t in Counter(t).items())
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be a bit trickier than it seems. The example you've given is slightly contrived, for example what about in the complicated situation where you have:

```py
t = ["A", "A", "A", "b", "b", "m"]
s = ["A", "A", "b", "b", "z"]
```

Neither `t` nor `s` are subsets of eachother. So IF you want to find if `s` is a subset of `t` (or in other words `s` is contained in `t` including duplicates) the problem has two checks:

- Does `s` have all the unique elements of `t`
- For each element of `s` contained in `t`, its frequency in `s` needs to be less than or equal to the corresponding frequency found in `t`

Here is a sample function that should solve you're problem:

```py
from collections import Counter


def is_subset(A: list[str], B: list[str]) -> bool:
    """is_subset tests if all elements of A
    are included in B.

    Args:
        A (list[str]): List of string elements.
        B (list[str]): List of string elements.

    Returns:
        bool: True if all elements of A (inc. duplicates) are in B.
    """
    # Create counter objs
    c_A = Counter(A)
    c_B = Counter(B)
    # First check to make sure unique elements are a subset
    # Or it fails at this stage
    uniq_A = c_A.keys()
    uniq_B = c_B.keys()
    if uniq_A <= uniq_B:
        return bool(c_B - c_A) if c_B != c_A else True
    return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = ["A", "A", "b", "b"]
    t = ["A", "A", "b", "b", "b"]
    k = ["A", "b", "z"]

    print(is_subset(t, t))  # True
    print(is_subset(k, s))  # False
    print(is_subset(s, t))  # True
```

Comment: You had the right idea with `Counter` difference, but doing it the other way around saves you all those clunky checks.

Comment: Fair, sometimes I like to be explicit at the expense of a few extra lines of code but I see what you mean.

Comment: Actually, your logic is flawed, e.g, if the two lists are the same, it returns `False`. The fact remains for each of the subsets elements you want the count to be completely covered. You test that by subtracting the super count from the sub count. Only that way reaching `0` gives you a definitive answer. Subtracting the sub count from the super count means any positive result or `0` are allowed with only negative results indicating failure. And negative results are exactly what a counter difference does **not** provide.

Comment: It was a simple case of adding a conditional to the edge case to solve the issue of equal sets.